# python jedi doesn't autocompleate

Tags: python-3.x, ide, python-jedi

I'm using Arch Linux. I'm trying to install jedi autocompletion but it's not working. I installed Atom extension, vim extension, jedi itself and I `ran export PYTHONSTARTUP="$(python -m jedi repl)"` but when I start to type neither Atom nor vim autocompleats. How can I fix it?

Comment: Setting `PYTHONSTARTUP` will not do anything for you. That helps when you want to work in the REPL.

Comment: You probably need to get way more specific about your problems, nobody will be able to help you with this error description.